# Convert file to base64 send via API

Tags: node.js, stream

I have used webshot module to take screenshot from html(or url), the screenshot file will be send via rest api to another server.

```
   var options = {
        shotSize: {
            width: 'all'
            , height: 'all'
        }
        , userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us)'
        + ' AppleWebKit/531.21.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B298g'
    };

    var renderStream = webshot('google.com');
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('google.png', {encoding: 'binary'});

    renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
        file.write(data.toString('binary'), 'binary');
        //code to encode base64Content and send api
    });
```

i don't know how to encode from file stream to send api.
I want to my body post api like this:

```
{
    api: "/file/upload",
    file: {
        base64Content: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAgABAgAAAQAxxxxx",
        lastModified: 1486989111609,
        lastModifiedDate: "2017-02-13T12:31:51.609Z",
        name: "14566344_1443324692346127_1005895525450508957_o.jpg",
        size: 408675,
        type: "image/jpeg"
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [stream-to-buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-buffer) module to get the content of the screenshot in one buffer and then simply convert it to base64 like this:

```js
'use strict';

const webshot = require('webshot');
const fs = require('fs');
const streamToBuffer = require('stream-to-buffer');

let options = {
 shotSize: {
  width: 'all'
  , height: 'all'
 }
 , userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us)'
 + ' AppleWebKit/531.21.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B298g'
};

let renderStream = webshot('google.com', options);

streamToBuffer(renderStream, (err, buffer) => {
 if (err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  throw err;
 }

 let base64String = buffer.toString('base64');
 //Now you have base64 encoded screen shot. Use it however you want.
 console.log(base64String);
});
```

Just for your reference. If you'd need to convert a stream to base64 on the fly and then pipe to another stream (say write to a file) you could do it by means of [base64-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-stream) like this:

```js
const base64 = require('base64-stream');

let renderStream = webshot('google.com', options);
let file = fs.createWriteStream('google.txt');

//So you can pipe it wherever needed, so it will bring base64 encoded data
renderStream.pipe(base64.encode()).pipe(file);
```